# Pandas: Create count cumsum column and reset if condition

Tags: python, pandas

**Overview**

When creating a conditional `count_cumsum` column in Pandas I have created a temporary `count` column then deleted this after the desired column was created.

**Code**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Level":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
                       "Price":[2,3,4,5,6,7,1,10]})
    
df["Count"] =  np.where((df.Price > df.Level),1,np.NaN) 
    
df['count_cumsum'] = df.Count.groupby(df.Count.isna().cumsum()).cumsum()

del df["Count"]

  Level Price   count_cumsum
0   1      2    1.0
1   2      3    2.0
2   3      4    3.0
3   4      5    4.0
4   5      6    5.0
5   6      7    6.0
6   7      1    NaN
7   8      10   1.0
```

**Question**

How can I use a zero instead of `NaN` for the `df["Count"]` column to keep `count_cumsum` as an int column and is there a simpler way to yield this output.

**Desired output**

```
  Level Price   count_cumsum
0   1      2    1
1   2      3    2
2   3      4    3
3   4      5    4
4   5      6    5
5   6      7    6
6   7      1    0
7   8      10   1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use zero instead of `NaN`, you can replace codes on `np.nan` with `0` and replace `isna()` by `eq(0)` in your code.  This should be simple and you should be able to do it yourself based on the hint here.  I will go straightly to the way to simplify the coding below:

You can simplify the processing logics as follows:

```
# Replace the `np.where` on the boolean condition and setting 0 or 1 according to condition by using `astype(int)` instead
m = (df.Price > df.Level).astype(int)    

#Use the series m for grouping and cumsum
df['count_cumsum'] = m.groupby(m.eq(0).cumsum()).cumsum()
```

In this way, you can simplify the code by:

1. without defining temporary column `df["Count"]` on `df` and delete it afterwards
2. simplify the code `np.where((df.Price > df.Level),1,0)` to simply converting the boolean condition `(df.Price > df.Level)` to integer (will give 0 and 1 for False and True respectively).

**Result:**

```
print(df)

   Level  Price  count_cumsum
0      1      2             1
1      2      3             2
2      3      4             3
3      4      5             4
4      5      6             5
5      6      7             6
6      7      1             0
7      8     10             1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the NaN's altogether with the clean and readable solution below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Level":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
                   "Price":[2,3,4,5,6,7,1,10]})

df["Count"] =  np.where((df.Price > df.Level),1,0) 

df['count_cumsum'] = df.Count.groupby((df.Count == 0).cumsum()).cumsum()

del df["Count"]

   Level  Price  count_cumsum
0      1      2             1
1      2      3             2
2      3      4             3
3      4      5             4
4      5      6             5
5      6      7             6
6      7      1             0
7      8     10             1
```

This leaves everything as an `int` type as well, which seems to be what you're after.